# In an Office Add-in developed using Office.js for Office Online, where is the process hosting the office application?

Tags: ms-office, office365, office-interop, office-js, office-addins

I have read the entire VSTO documentation to start with and skimmed over most of the Office Add-ins (office.js) documentation on MSDN but not found the answer to my question.

Could you please provide me with an answer and also, if possible, please point me to the page on MSDN that answers my question?

**Question**

In a scenario where the client computer does not have Microsoft Office installed, and is using a browser to access Office Online, and he loads an Office add-in written using Office.js, in such a scenario, where is the computer that hosts the COM objects and the Office process they reside in?

Here is my understanding of the elements involved in using Office.js add-ins:

1. There's the Open XML document that has the data. This is just dead-meat. It had to be loaded into a process.

   Earlier, *that process* used to be the unmanaged WINWORD.EXE (or EXCEL.EXE or POWERPNT.EXE or another office application) process.

   Now, with office.js, when using Office Online, i.e. the Web client, the unmanaged Office process *still has to be allocated in memory in some computer*? Basically, that's the core of my question.

   My guess is
   that it has to, and that the process may be run remotely on a
   server. The document itself may be hosted remotely, which isn't a
   big deal but the process, too, is required and in the case of Office
   Online, the unmanaged office process is run on a remote computer. It
   is this assumption I want to confirm or invalidate.
2. There's the client UI. This used to be a mesh of unmanaged C++ code within the office application and managed UI created by .NET using VSTO and Windows Forms or WPF. Now, with Office.js, this is done using HTML/CSS/JavaScript and can be loaded by any kind of a client (desktop/Web).
3. The process hosting the document and providing the underlying `Document`, `Bookmark`, `Range` *et al* objects. My question is -- for Office Online clients that do not have MS Office installed on the client computer, where is this process now if they use Office Add-ins written using office.js?

Am I wrong in assuming that the JavaScript API for Office Add-ins merely calls into the existing Office COM infrastructure we already know about? If I am right, then where is the machine that hosts the Winword.exe (or whichever Office application) process?

Comment: There is a web server somewhere... https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/overview/office-add-ins#anatomy-of-an-office-add-in

Comment: Thank you for reading my question and responding. I had read that page from the documentation before posting this question. You see, it does not say that the Office process, for e.g. WINWORD.EXE runs on the server. There is no page that talks about "how" this works. Are you suggesting that the web server spins off an Office application process? Does it do a separate process for every Web request / office.js client? Could you please point me to a page that explains all of this? That page only says there's a web server where you xcopy deploy your HTML/JS/CSS and any server side code you have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer the question of where the code is executed:  There are no "COM" objects per se (the new wave of Office.js APIs is not based on the VBA COM objects, at least not directly).   But there is indeed a backing server that has the document open and in-memory.  In the case of Excel, the Excel Online front-end is a fairly "thin" layer, and almost all operations are executed by the supporting server.  That server doesn't run EXCEL.exe directly, but it has a web service that is kinda-sorta-like Excel (and that shares a lot of the same underlying C++ code), which runs in a "headless" mode, one instance per document.  In the case of Word, on the other hand, Word Online has a lot more business logic that it can execute locally, and so a lot of the operations are executed on the browser and sync back up to the server at idle time (much like end-user operations), but there is still a backing server that serves the appropriate data to the Word Online front-end, and that processes some operations (e.g., `range.getOoxml()`, or `image.getImage()`).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks so much, Michael. Two follow-up questions. (1) What's a "headless" mode? (2) Running an instance of the office application process for each document must take up a lot of hardware because each instance would take up a lot of RAM and so a single machine could only bear two to three instances?

Comment: By "headless" I mean UI-less.  Namely, it's not Excel.exe as you know it, but rather a web server that encapsulates the core Excel computation engine.  I think that also allows more such processes to run per machine, though ultimately it's an implementation detail that should be 100% invisible to the developer and user

Answer (score 2):

Office Web Add-ins (office-js) are web apps that leverage a specific library (office-js) to facilitate communication between the add-in and the host application.

As these add-ins are simply web apps, they work across the various Office platforms (Windows, Web, Mac, iOS). For browser based Office editions, add-ins are surfaced in an `iframe`. For native editions they are hosted in an embedded browser (IE11, Webkit, etc. depending on the platform).

Add-ins consist of two components, an XML manifest and the web app. The manifest can be loaded from a number of locations from directly side-loading, to a network share, to the [Office Store](http://store.office.com). The web app is hosted wherever you would normally host your web apps (I recommend [Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com) but then I'm a bit biased). They are never hosted by Microsoft directly.